# Div color not contouring all elements

Tags: html

I am trying to give a green backgound to my elements but my div is not contouring all the expected elements. I tried to look for a problem in my div but they seem to be perfectly fine

Here is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
  <title>CLOUD</title>
  <style>
.bg {
      /* The image used */
      background-image: url({{ url_for('static', filename='Picture13.png')
    }
  }
  );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.divSquare {
  margin:4px;
  border:1px solid black;
  float: left
}
  </style>
</head>

<body class="bg">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu">
  <label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
                <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
                <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
                <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
            </label>
  <div id="sidebarMenu">
    <ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
      <li><a href="/upload">UPLOAD</a></li>
      <li><a href="/download">DOWNLOAD</a></li>
      <li><a href="/filesystem">FILESYSTEM</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div style="padding-top: 21%; padding-left: 7%; background-color: green">
    <div style="float:left; width: 15%;padding-right: 2%; padding-left: 2%;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>File Type</label>
        <select class="browser-default custom-select" name=e xtensions method="POST" action="/">
          {% for extension in extensions %}
          <option value="{{extension}}" SELECTED>{{extension}}</option>" {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style=" float:left; padding-right: 3%;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Parent Folder</label>
        <select class="browser-default custom-select" name=d irs method="POST" action="/">
          {% for dir in dirs %}
          <option value="{{dir}}" SELECTED>{{dir}}</option>" {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row" style="float:left">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Uploaded Date</label>
        <div class="col-10" style="padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; width:250px">
          <input class="form-control" type="date" value="2020-09-01" name="date" id="example-date-input">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

As a result it give the following output :  [image]

Why are the elements with the name extensions and date do not have a green background aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
        <title>CLOUD</title>
        <style>
            .bg {
                /* The image used */
                background-image: url({{ url_for('static', filename='Picture13.png')}});
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    }
    .divSquare{
        margin:4px; border:1px solid black; float: left
    }

    .mainDiv{
      display: flex;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body class="bg">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu">
        <label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
            <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
            <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
            <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
        </label>
    <div id="sidebarMenu">
        <ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
            <li><a href="/upload">UPLOAD</a></li>
            <li><a href="/download">DOWNLOAD</a></li>
            <li><a href="/filesystem">FILESYSTEM</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mainDiv" style="padding-top: 21%; background-color: green">
        <div style="float:left; width: 15%;padding-right: 2%; padding-left: 2%;" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>File Type</label>
                <select class="browser-default custom-select" name= extensions method="POST" action="/" >
                    {% for extension in extensions %}
                    <option value= "{{extension}}" SELECTED>{{extension}}</option>"
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="padding-right: 3%;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Parent Folder</label>
                <select class="browser-default custom-select" name= dirs method="POST" action="/" >
                    {% for dir in dirs %}
                    <option value= "{{dir}}" SELECTED>{{dir}}</option>"
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Uploaded Date</label>
                <div class="col-10" style="padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; width:250px">
                    <input class="form-control" type="date" value="2020-09-01" name="date" id="example-date-input">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes thank you. Can you please explain why you added display flex and removed 2 float:left

Comment: If you have padding on your parent div, which is inner indentation, float property on his children makes them float over the size of that padding. And flex box makes elements easy to position. The default value of justify-content is row, so children are aligned in a row. In a more clear way, you should in adition replace padding-top with height and add align-items: flex-end to the parrent div.